# Parsing text file lines in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a txt file with data such as following:

```
regNumber     FName         Score1   Score2   Score3
385234     John Snow         90.0     56.0     60.8
38345234   Michael Bolton    30.0     26.5     
38500234   Tim Cook          40.0     56.5     20.2
1547234    Admin__One        10.0         
                      ...
```

The data is separated only by whitespace.

Now, my issue is that as some of the data is missing, I cannot simply do as following:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("file.txt")

file >> regNo >> fName >> lName >> score1 >> score2 >> score3
```

(I'm not sure if code above is right, but trying to explain the idea)

What I want to do is roughly this:

```
cout << "Reg Number: ";
cin >> regNo;

cout << "Name: ";
cin >> name;

if(regNo == regNumber && name == fname) {
  cout << "Access granted" << endl;
}
```

This is what I've tried/where I'm at:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("users.txt");
string line;

    
while(getline(file, line)) {
   stringstream ss(line);
   string word;
   while(ss >> word) {
      cout << word << "\t";
   }
   cout << " " << endl;
}
```

I can output the file entirely, my issue is when it comes to picking the parts, e.g. only getting the `regNumber` or the name.

Comment: Which fields are valid to be missing? Can regNumber be missing? Can user name(s)? Can both? If you can guarantee some specific fields are always available then the solution is simplified.

Comment: only scores can be missing, regNumber and names can't

Answer (score 1):

I would read the whole line in at once and then just substring it (since you suggest that these are fixed width fields)

Answer (score 0):

Handling the spaces between the words of the names are tricky, but its apparent from your file that each column starts at a fixed offset. You can use this to extract the information you want. For example, in order to read the names, you can read the line starting at the offset that `FName` starts, and ending at the offset that `Score1` starts. Then you can remove trailing white spaces from the string like this:

```
string A = "Tim Cook       ";
auto index = A.find_last_not_of(' ');
A.erase(index + 1);
```

Comment: It isn’t apparent to me, and I wouldn’t trust a data file to maintain fixed-size fields unless that is _explicitly_ in the file’s spec.

Comment: Of course the file provider should provide you with the data structure, but the question hasn't provided one. If the file doesn't have fixed-size fields then it would be hard to read it programmatically if column values would be missing from the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I can’t sleep and so decided to go bonkers and demonstrate just how tricky input is, *especially* when you have freeform data. The following code contains plenty of commentary on reading freeform data that may be missing.

```
#include <ciso646>
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>


// Useful Stuff

template <typename T> T& lvalue( T&& arg ) { return arg; }

using strings = std::deque <std::string> ;
auto split( const std::string& s )
{
  return strings
  (
    std::istream_iterator <std::string> ( lvalue( std::istringstream{ s } ) ),
    std::istream_iterator <std::string> ()
  );
}

template <typename T>
auto string_to( const std::string & s )
{
  T value;
  std::istringstream ss( s );
  return ((ss >> value) and (ss >> std::ws).eof())
    ? value
    : std::optional<T> { };
}

std::string trim( const std::string& s )
{
  auto R = s.find_last_not_of ( " \f\n\r\t\v" ) + 1;
  auto L = s.find_first_not_of( " \f\n\r\t\v" );
  return s.substr( L, R-L );
}


// Each record is stored as a “User”.
// “Users” is a complete dataset of records.

struct User
{
  int                       regNumber;
  std::vector <std::string> names;
  std::vector <double>      scores;
};
using Users = std::vector <User> ;


// This is stuff you would put in the .cpp file, not an .hpp file.
// But since this is a single-file example, it goes here.
namespace detail::Users
{
  static const char * FILE_HEADER = "regNumber     FName         Score1   Score2   Score3\n";
  static const int    REGNUMBER_WIDTH   = 11;
  static const int    NAMES_TOTAL_WIDTH = 18;
  static const int    SCORE_WIDTH       =  9;
  static const int    SCORE_PRECISION   =  1;
}


// Input is always the hardest part, and provides a WHOLE lot of caveats to deal with.
// Let us take them one at a time.
//
// Each user is a record composed of ONE OR MORE elements on a line of text.
// The elements are:
//   (regNumber)? (name)* (score)*
//
// The way we handle this is:
//  (1) Read the entire line
//  (2) Split the line into substrings
//  (3) If the first element is a regNumber, grab it
//  (4) Grab any trailing floating point values as scores
//  (5) Anything remaining must be names
//
// There are comments in the code below which enable you to produce a hard failure
// if any record is incorrect, however you define that. A “hard fail” sets the fail
// state on the input stream, which will stop all further input on the stream until
// the caller uses the .clear() method on the stream.
//
// The default action is to stop reading records if a failure occurs. This way the
// CALLER can decide whether to clear the error and try to read more records.
//
// Finally, we use decltype liberally to make it easier to modify the User struct
// without having to watch out for type problems with the stream extraction operator.

// Input a single record

std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& ins, User& user )
{
  // // Hard fail helper (named lambda)
  // auto failure = [&ins]() -> std::istream&
  // {
  //   ins.setstate( std::ios::failbit );
  //   return ins;
  // };

  // You should generally clear your target object when writing stream extraction operators
  user = User{};

  // Get a single record (line) from file
  std::string s;
  if (!getline( ins, s )) return ins;

  // Split the record into fields
  auto fields = split( s );

  // Skip (blank lines) and (file headers)
  static const strings header = split( detail::Users::FILE_HEADER );
  if (fields.empty() or fields == header) return operator >> ( ins, user );

  // The optional regNumber must appear first
  auto reg_number = string_to <decltype(user.regNumber)> ( fields.front() );
  if (reg_number)
  {
    user.regNumber = *reg_number;
    fields.pop_front();
  }

  // Optional scores must appear last
  while (!fields.empty())
  {
    auto score = string_to <std::remove_reference <decltype(user.scores.front())> ::type> ( fields.back() );
    if (!score) break;
    user.scores.insert( user.scores.begin(), *score );
    fields.pop_back();
  }
  // if (user.scores.size() > 3) return failure();  // is there a maximum number of scores?

  // Any remaining fields are names.
  // if (fields.empty())    return failure();  // at least one name required?
  // if (fields.size() > 2) return failure();  // maximum of two names?
  for (const auto& name : fields)
  {
    // (You could also check that each name matches a valid regex pattern, etc)
    user.names.push_back( name );
  }

  // If we got this far, all is good. Return the input stream.
  return ins;
}

// Input a complete User dataset

std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& ins, Users& users )
{
  // This time, do NOT clear the target object! This permits the caller to read
  // multiple files and combine them! The caller is also now responsible to
  // provide a new/empty/clear target Users object to avoid combining datasets.

  // Read all records
  User user;
  while (ins >> user) users.push_back( user );

  // Return the input stream
  return ins;
}


// Output, by comparison, is fabulously easy.
//
// I won’t bother to explain any of this, except to recall that
// the User is stored as a line-object record -- that is, it must
// be terminated by a newline. Hence we output the newline in the
// single User stream insertion operator (output operator) instead
// of the Users output operator.

// Output a single User record

std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& outs, const User& user )
{
  std::ostringstream userstring;
  userstring << std::setw( detail::Users::REGNUMBER_WIDTH ) << std::left << user.regNumber;

  std::ostringstream names;
  for (const auto& name : user.names) names << name << " ";
  userstring << std::setw( detail::Users::NAMES_TOTAL_WIDTH ) << std::left << names.str();

  for (auto score : user.scores)
    userstring 
      << std::left << std::setw( detail::Users::SCORE_WIDTH ) 
      << std::fixed << std::setprecision( detail::Users::SCORE_PRECISION ) 
      << score;

  return outs << trim( userstring.str() ) << "\n";  // <-- output of newline
}

// Output a complete User dataset

std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& outs, const Users& users )
{
  outs << detail::Users::FILE_HEADER;
  for (const auto& user : users) outs << user;
  return outs;
}


int main()
{
  // Example input. Notice that any field may be absent.
  std::istringstream input(
    "regNumber     FName         Score1   Score2   Score3 \n"
    "385234     John Snow         90.0     56.0     60.8  \n"
    "38345234   Michael Bolton    30.0     26.5           \n"
    "38500234   Tim Cook          40.0     56.5     20.2  \n"
    "1547234    Admin__One        10.0                    \n"
    "                                                     \n" // blank line --> skipped
    "           Jon Bon Jovi                              \n"
    "11111                        22.2                    \n"
    "                             33.3                    \n"
    "4444                                                 \n"
    "55         Justin Johnson                            \n"
  );
  Users        users;
  input     >> users;
  std::cout << users;
}
```

To compile with MSVC:

```
cl /EHsc /W4 /Ox /std:c++17 a.cpp
```

To compile with Clang:

```
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O3 -std=c++17 a.cpp
```

To compile with MinGW/GCC/etc use the same as Clang, substituting `g++` for `clang++`, naturally.

As a final note, if you can make your data file much more strict life will be significantly easier. For example, if you can say that you are always going to used fixed-width fields you can use [Shahriar’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70703361/2706707), for example, or [pm100’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70703644/2706707), which I upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

I would define a `Person` class.
This knows how to read and write a `Person` on one line.

```
class Person
{
    int                 regNumber;
    std::string         FName;
    std::array<float,3> scope;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Person const& p)
    {
        return p << regNumber << " " << FName << " " << scope[0] << " " << scope[1] << " " << scope[2] << "\n";
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Person& p)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(s, line);

        bool   valid = true;
        Person tmp;     // Holds value while we check
        // Handle Line.
        // Handle missing data.
        // And update tmp to the correct state.

        if (valid) {
            // The conversion worked.
            // So update the object we are reading into.
            swap(p, tmp);
        }
        else {
            // The conversion failed.
            // Set the stream to bad so we stop reading.
            s.setstate(std::ios::bad);
        }
        return s;
    }
    void swap(Person& other) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(regNumber, other.regNumber);
        swap(FName,     other.FName);
        swap(scope,     other.scope);
    }
};
```

Then your main becomes much simpler.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("Data");
    Person        person;
    while (file >> person)
    {
        std::cout << person;
    }
}
```

It also becomes easier to handle your second part.
You load each person then ask the `Person` object to validate that credentials.

```
class Person
{
     // STUFF From before:
    public:
        bool validateUser(int id, std::string const& name) const
        {
             return id == regNumber && name == FName;
        }
};

int main()
{

    int reg = getUserReg();
    std::string  name = getUserName();

    std::ifstream file("Data");
    Person        person;

    while (file >> person)
    {
        if (person.validateUser(reg, name))
        {
            std::cout << "Access Granted\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: None of this helps solves OP’s problem...